# NSJSONSerialization not handling negative integers

Tags: json, cocoa, nsjsonserialization, negative-number

I’m trying to parse an JSON file into an NSArray and it all works well for positive numbers. However all the negative integers in that JSON file produce high numbers like “[11]    __NSCFNumber *  (long)72057594037927933”. How can i get that to work?

Here is my JSON file:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10,-11]
```

and here the code:

```
 NSError* error;
 NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://some/json/file.json"]];
 NSMutableArray* array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: is that really your JSON file?  JSON files usually have various attributes and keys and not just a straight Objective-C-looking array.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann that’s all there is to it, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode doesn't always print nice values into the Debug area of the Xcode (where live values for the context appear).

I dropped your code into my own project and when I step through each line, I do see the "`eachNumber    __NSCFNumber *  (long)72057594037927934 {0xbfffffffffffffe3}` bits, but if I try print out the values of the array into the console, you'll see the correct "`-2`" result.

Try it yourself.  I added in these lines right after yours:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSLog(@"array is %@", array);

for(id eachNumber in array)
{
    NSLog(@"eachNumber is %@", eachNumber);
}
```